# Split String without commas

Tags: android, arrays, random

I've got a method that generates 9 random numbers, and at least I store them on a String to show on the console. This is the function:

```
public static String GenerateNumbers(){
    int[] NumberList = new int[9];

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        NumberList[i] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*(100-10+1)+10);
    }
    Arrays.sort(NumberList);
    String[] ar = Arrays.toString(NumberList).split("[\\[\\]]")[1].split(", ");
    String a = Arrays.toString(ar);
    return a;
}
```

When I see this String on the console, is like : `[20, 28, 33, 46, 46, 57, 81, 83, 90]`

What I need to see is: [20 28 33 46 46 57 81 83 90]

And it would be perfect if: 20 28 33 46 46 57 81 83 90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one line of code just before you return your string, and you will have your perfect output:

```
public static String GenerateNumbers(){
    int[] NumberList = new int[9];

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        NumberList[i] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*(100-10+1)+10);
    }
    Arrays.sort(NumberList);
    String[] ar = Arrays.toString(NumberList).split("[\\[\\]]")[1].split(", ");
    String a = Arrays.toString(ar);

    //add this line to remove characters you don't need
    a = a.replace("[", "").replace(",", "").replace("]", "");

    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [TextUtils.join()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#join%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) to join an array with a `CharSequence` (which can be `String` also).

```
public static String GenerateNumbers(){
    Integer[] NumberList = new Integer[9];

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        NumberList[i] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*(100-10+1)+10);
    }
    Arrays.sort(NumberList);
    String a = TextUtils.join(" ",NumberList);
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "[20, 28, 33, 46, 46, 57, 81, 83, 90]";
    String b = a.substring(a.indexOf("[")+1, a.indexOf("]"));
    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(b, ",");
    while(token.hasMoreElements()){
        System.out.print(token.nextElement());
    }
}


//output
20 28 33 46 46 57 81 83 90
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
public static String GenerateNumbers(){
    int[] NumberList = new int[9];

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        NumberList[i] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*(100-10+1)+10);
    }
    Arrays.sort(NumberList);
    String a="";
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        a+= NumberList[i]+" ";
    }
    a = a.trim();
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change Your method like this..

```
public static String GenerateNumbers() {
    int[] NumberList = new int[9];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        NumberList[i] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 10 + 1)
                + 10);
    }
    Arrays.sort(NumberList);
    String a = Arrays.toString(NumberList);
    a = a.replaceAll(",", "");
    a = a.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
    return a;
}
```

OutPut:

```
16 28 30 37 45 70 73 85 92
```